# Which species of parrot learn things fast and make a great pet?

Tags: parrots

Which species of parrot are the smartest and make the best pet?

Comment: I think it is African grey parrot.

Comment: you have made two questions here,the smartest parrot might not be the best pet and the best pet might not be the smartest one.

Comment: All birds are different and have different needs. For example, Macaws are very intelligent but do _extremely_ poorly if their owner ever has to go away on a vacation. So looking at just one quality is a poor way to judge how a new pet will work with your lifestyle.